# Проблема работы со строкой в VBA

Tags: vba

Я читаю RecordSet в Access и хочу занести значение в переменную типа String.

Так вот, после 255 символа все символы заменяются знаками "?". `Debug.Pring` так показывается...

У VBA какое-то жесткое ограничение? Как можно уйти от этой проблемы?

Comment: *Я читаю RecordSet в Access* Recordset - DAO? ADO? Какой сервер? какой тип поля? *после 255 символа все символы заменяются знаками "?"* В рекордсете и переменной? только в переменной? как присваиваете? Да и вообще - код в студию, слишком много гадать... *У VBA какое-то жесткое ограничение?* Ну да... где-то чуть меньше 2 гигов на переменную

Comment: @Akina, стандартный который Access предлагает. Его я получаю через CurrentDb. Читаю данные из Access. тип MEMO.

Comment: *стандартный который Access предлагает. Его я получаю через CurrentDb* Это DAO (ну как можно не знать, что используешь?). *тип MEMO* Для получения данных из поля МЕМО следует использовать метод GetChunk объекта DAO.Recordset.Field.

Comment: Ругается на ошибочный тип данных поля.

Comment: Значит, что-то неверно делаете. Воспользуйтесь примером из встроенной справки (Field.GetChunk Method).

Comment: @Akina, ничего не понимаю. Убрал NZ из запроса, который формирует мне RecordSet и все заработала без Chunk.

Comment: @Akina, встроенные функции могут приводить к подобным искажениям?

Comment: Проверьте какая длина текстового поля задана в вашей базе данных